LaTeX - Complex running header/footer and margins with Tables
This is a duplicated question for the https://stackoverflow.com/q/78571873/6217684, as therein no replies are being received (I realize I posted it in not the right community).
I need to reproduce a custom WYSIWG template that has:

Table in the Footer,
Tables in the Left margin (with text in 0 and 90 degrees orientations),
Disclaimer + vertical Rule in the Right Margin,
Horizontal rules and Text in the Header

So, basically the body is fully framed.
All the above shall be present in all the pages. However, the cover page shall in addition have additional tables in the body area.
Attached pics are the sample to be replicated (items in curly brackets {variable} are variables).


I have managed to reach some level or replication in LateX (see below pic) by following the answers in several other posts, but, after several days of trying, not being able to fully match the sample: non-uniform textwidth nor textheight nor margins, and in addition getting multiple errors during compilation.

With this code I'm having the following issues:

Coverpage is "hardcoded",
Pagelayout is not uniform along the full document,
Title block proportions are hardcoded (not a function of paperwidth, paperheight),
Three (3 no.) unintended pages are being created:


A blank 2nd page
A blank 2nd last page
The last page


Location of elements in the coverpage depends on the text length, therefore no dentical position for all items.

I would appreciate any help to make this LaTeX code clean and to really replicate the WYSIWYG sample, and fix the errors being thrown.
Hereto is the code (I'm using TeXstudio 4.8.0 with default PdfLaTeX compiler)
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[letterpaper, textheight=619pt,  headsep=40.0pt,  footskip=30pt,  bindingoffset=100pt, textwidth=383pt, includemp=false,  marginparsep=70.0pt, showframe=false, showcrop, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
%Original
%\usepackage[letterpaper, textheight=20.35cm,  headsep=60.0pt,  footskip=50pt, hdivide={5cm,,}, bindingoffset=1cm, textwidth=13.5cm, includemp=false,  marginparsep=70.0pt, showframe=false, showcrop, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
% 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%-----DEFINITIONS-------------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\title{My first LaTeX document}
%-CLIENT INFORMATION-
\newcommand{\ClientProjectCode}{Project Code}
\newcommand{\ClientProjectName}{PROJECT NAME }
\newcommand{\Location}{Location Type}
\newcommand{\PlantName}{Location 1}
\newcommand{\PlantNumber}{NNN}


%-DOCUMENT INFORMATION-
\newcommand{\ClientDocIndex}{8}
\newcommand{\ClientDocType}{RT}
\newcommand{\ClientDocNumber}{05-wer520}
\newcommand{\ClientRev}{0}
\newcommand{\DocTitle}{REPORT ANALYSIS}
\newcommand{\ProjectCode}{NNNNNx}
\newcommand{\Unit}{NNN}
\newcommand{\DocCode}{5522RT}
\newcommand{\SerialCode}{01}
\newcommand{\Rev}{0}

%Fullnames
\newcommand{\WrittenBy}{Fulano}
\newcommand{\CheckedBy}{Merlano}
\newcommand{\ApprovedBy}{thebest}
\newcommand{\AuthorizeedBy}{Sultano Sultania}
\newcommand{\CertifiedBy}{thebest}
\newcommand{\ConstAgency}{Sultano Sultania}
\newcommand{\Operations}{Sultano}

%Initials

%Revisions
\newcommand{\FsRev}{\vphantom{2} A}
\newcommand{\FsDate}{05/12/2024}
\newcommand{\FsDesc}{Issue for Construction}
\newcommand{\ScRev}{\vphantom{2} B}
\newcommand{\ScDate}{05/12/2024}
\newcommand{\ScDesc}{Issue for...}
\newcommand{\TdRev}{\vphantom{2} }
\newcommand{\TdDate}{05/12/2024}
\newcommand{\TdDesc}{Issue for...}
\newcommand{\FhRev}{\vphantom{2} }
\newcommand{\FhDate}{05/12/2024}
\newcommand{\FhDesc}{Issue for...}
%-----------------------------------------


%-----------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\vspace{0.91cm}\tiny KKKER3455 \\}%2616-ENG (03/99) \\}
\fancyhead[C]{\\\hrulefill\\ \adjustbox{padding=0ex -2ex 0ex 1ex}{\large CLIENT COMPANY \\ \vspace{-0.2cm} \hrulefill  }} 
\fancyheadoffset[h]{8.45mm}
\fancyhfoffset[L]{15.5mm}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
%--Footer------------
\reversemarginpar
\marginnote{%%
%---------side rotated table 1
\tiny   Template code 
\begin{turn}{90}
\tiny
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{2em} | m{1cm}| m{2cm} | m{3cm} | m{0.5cm} | m{0.5cm} | m{0.5cm} | m{0.5cm} | }%{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        REV NO. & \adjustbox{padding=0ex 1ex 0ex 2ex}{DATE} & Job & DESCRIPTION & ENGG & CERT & PMT & \adjustbox{padding=-1ex 0ex 0ex 0ex}{OPRNS}\\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding=0ex 1.2ex 0ex 1.7ex}{\FsRev} &  \FsDate      &   \ClientProjectCode     &    \FsDesc     &      &      &     &       \\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding=0ex 1.2ex 0ex 1.7ex}{\ScRev} &  \ScDate      &   \ClientProjectCode     &    \ScDesc     &      &      &     &       \\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding=0ex 1.2ex 0ex 1.7ex}{\TdRev} &  \TdDate          &        &             &      &      &     &       \\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding=0ex 1.2ex 0ex 1.7ex}{\FhRev} &  \FhDate          &        &             &      &      &     &       \\ \hline
        
    \end{tabular}%
\end{turn}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\tiny
    \begin{tabularx}{2.47cm} { 
            | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
            |}
        %\begin{tabular}{|p|}
        \hline
        \adjustbox{padding= 2ex 0ex 0ex 1ex}{DISCIPLINE} \newline \adjustbox{padding=   2ex 0ex 0ex 0.5ex}{ENGINEER} \newline \adjustbox{padding=   0ex 2ex 0ex 2ex}{\WrittenBy} \newline \adjustbox{padding=   0ex 1ex 0ex 0ex}{DATE: \today} \\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding= 2ex 0ex 0ex 1ex}{PROJECT} \newline \adjustbox{padding=  2ex 0ex 0ex 0.5ex}{ENGINEER} \newline \adjustbox{padding=0ex 2ex 0ex 2ex}{\WrittenBy} \newline \adjustbox{padding=  0ex 1ex 0ex 0ex}{DATE: \today} \\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding= 2ex 2ex 0ex 1ex}{CERTIFIED} \newline \adjustbox{padding=    0ex 2ex 0ex 3ex}{\ConstAgency} \newline \adjustbox{padding= 0ex 1ex 0ex 0ex}{DATE: \today}  \\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding= 2ex 0ex 0ex 1ex}{CONSTRUCTION} \newline \adjustbox{padding= 2ex 0ex 0ex 0.5ex}{AGENCY} \newline \adjustbox{padding=0ex 2ex 0ex 2ex}{\WrittenBy} \newline \adjustbox{padding=    0ex 1ex 0ex 0ex}{DATE: \today} \\ \hline
        \adjustbox{padding= 2ex 2ex 0ex 1ex}{OPERATIONS} \newline \adjustbox{padding=   0ex 2ex 0ex 3ex}{\ConstAgency} \newline \adjustbox{padding= 0ex 1ex 0ex 0ex}{DATE: \today}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
%---------side rotated table 2
\begin{turn}{90}
    %\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
    \tiny
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0.1cm}
        
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{3.6cm} | p{1.8cm} | }%{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \adjustbox{padding=1.2ex 1ex 0ex 1.5ex}{ \textbf{\scalebox{1.2}[1.5]{REVISION CERTIFICATION}}} &  \adjustbox{padding=0ex 0ex 0ex 0ex}{\textbf{\makecell{Entity \\ \underline{VERIFICATION}}} }  \\
         THIS INDICATES THAT~REV.~NO.~\underline{\hspace{3pt}\Rev\hspace{3pt}}
         OF THIS DRAWING IS COVERED, FOR ALL APPROVAL/CERTIFICATION REQUIREMENTS, BY DRAWING COMPLETION CERTIFICATE ~NO.~\underline{\hspace{60pt}}  & \vspace{2ex} \hspace{1.65cm}  \underline{\hspace{1.65cm}} \scalebox{0.8}[1.0]{CONTROL NUMBER} \vspace{1ex} BY:~\underline{\hspace{1.2cm}} \vspace{1ex} DATE:~\underline{\hspace{1.15cm}}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{turn}
%--
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
%--
}[-9.58in]%%
\resizebox{16cm}{!}{
    \newline
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1in}rc|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\DocTitle} & {\scriptsize   DWG. TYPE}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize PLANT NO.}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize TypeIdx}             & \scriptsize DRAWING NO.       & \scriptsize  SHT NO.           & \scriptsize REV.NO.           \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-8} 
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\ClientProjectName}       &      \ClientDocType           & \multirowcell{2}{{\PlantNumber}} & \multirowcell{2}{{\ClientDocIndex}} & \multirowcell{2}{{\large \ClientDocNumber}} & \multirowcell{3}{\thepage\   of  \pageref{LastPage}} & {} \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\Location}                         &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                   &                  &       \large\ClientRev           \\ \cline{1-6}
        \PlantName & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\scriptsize Country} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\scriptsize Job:}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\ClientProjectCode}                                      &                   &                   \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}

}
%--end of sidetable--------------
%Draws the rightside vertical line to complete the frame.
\newtoks\oldoutput
\oldoutput=\expandafter{\the\output}%
\output{%
    \setbox255\vbox to 0pt{%
        \hbox to 0pt{%
            \vsize\ht255%
            \vbox to 8.377in{%
                \vss
                \hbox to 5.656in{%
                    \hss
                    \vrule height 9.37in width 0.4pt%
                }%
            }\hss
        }\vss
        \box255%
    }%
    \the\oldoutput
}%
%-----


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{13cm}[!H]{|>{\hsize=0.22\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.12\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.36\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.18\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.12\hsize}X|}
    \hline
    \centering Project N° & \centering Unit & \centering Document code & Serial N° & Rev. \\ \hline
    \centering \ProjectCode & \centering \Unit & \centering \DocCode & \centering \SerialCode & \Rev \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\centering
\vskip 50pt \par
\includegraphics[scale=2]{./Figures/placeholder}

\vskip 0.4in \par
\large{\ClientProjectCode}
\newline
\vskip 0.15in \par
\large{\ClientProjectName \newline AT \PlantName}
\newline
\vskip 0.5in \par
\begin{spacing}{1.7}
    {\LARGE \DocTitle}
\end{spacing}
%\newline
%\vskip 50pt \par % Si el titulo es de dos lineas
\vskip 70pt \par % Si el titulo es de una linea
\large{PREPARED BY}
\newline
\vskip 0.5in \par
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./Figures/placeholder}
\vskip 0.55in \par 
%Titleblock
\tiny
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{13cm}[b]{|>{\hsize=0.05\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.09\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.26\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.17\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.17\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.26\hsize}X|}
    \hline
        \centering \FsRev &  \FsDate & \centering \FsDesc & \centering \WrittenBy & \centering  \CheckedBy & \ApprovedBy \ / \AuthorizeedBy \\ \hline
        
        \centering \FsRev &  \FsDate & \centering \FsDesc & \centering \WrittenBy & \centering  \CheckedBy & \ApprovedBy \ / \AuthorizeedBy \\ \hline
        
        \centering \FsRev &  \FsDate & \centering \FsDesc & \centering \WrittenBy & \centering  \CheckedBy & \ApprovedBy \ / \AuthorizeedBy \\ \hline
        
        \centering \FsRev &  \FsDate & \centering \FsDesc & \centering \WrittenBy & \centering  \CheckedBy & \ApprovedBy \ / \AuthorizeedBy \\ \hline
        
        \centering \FsRev &  \FsDate & \centering \FsDesc & \centering \WrittenBy & \centering  \CheckedBy & \ApprovedBy \ / \AuthorizeedBy \\ \hline
        
    \centering Rev. & \centering DATE & \centering STATUS & \centering WRITTEN BY & \centering CHECKED BY & APPROV BY / AUTHOR BY \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{DOCUMENT REVISIONS} \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{spacing}
%


%-------Different page Layout
\newgeometry{textheight=20.35cm,  headsep=60.0pt,  footskip=50pt, hdivide={5cm,,}, bindingoffset=1cm, textwidth=13.5cm, includemp=false,  marginparsep=70.0pt}
% 
\normalsize
\justifying
%\Raggedright
%-------Contenido


\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{SCOPE}

 



\section{REFERENCE DOCUMENTS}
\small
\begin{description}

\end{description}


\normalsize
\section{CALCULATION METHOD}


\lipsum[1-10]
    \end{document}


If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Please edit your SO post to include a link to this question.

Well it is rather trivial to add something into every margin: create a few boxes with the correct content and then place them with a shipout hook.  Do not redefine \output. You don't need that, and you clearly do not have the skills to handle such a change and will only break LaTeX. Generally you should not assume that someone will recreate a complex layout for you for free - it takes to much time to get all details right.  So instead try to make a simplified example that focus on your main problem.

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I'd rather deleted it from SO simplify the things.

This looks like a job for flowfram!  Either that or do the whole page as a tikzpictuire.

Solved using the approach sketched by Ulrike, i.e., using a shipout hook.
For those facing similar needs, I used the package atbegshi with
\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \put(){}
}

This is described in the package manual and produced perfect results!
